# argparse set default to multiple args

Tags: python, argparse

I want use argparse to specify a option that take three integer values: like specifying a range: start, end, step.

```
parser.add_argument('--range', nargs=3, metavar=('start', 'end', 'step'), 
             type=int, help="specify a range')
```

However, it is not clear to me how to provide default values to all three values. Do I need to define it as string and parse it myself?

Comment: It would have helped if you had provided a complete, short (10 lines is probably enough) demonstration program. Now I have to write one to test my answer. :(

Comment: sorry about the test program, default does take a list. appreciate the help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
parser.add_argument('--range', default=[4,3,2], 
                    nargs=3, metavar=('start', 'end', 'step'),
                    type=int, help='specify a range')
```

Demo program:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--range', default=[4,3,2], nargs=3, metavar=('start', 'end', 'step'),
             type=int, help='specify a range')
print parser.parse_args([])

# prints Namespace(range=[4, 3, 2])
```

Answer (score 6):

When using `nargs`, to provide multiple default values, define them in a list - see the third code snippet of [this section](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#formatter-class) of the docs, which contains the following example:

```
parser.add_argument('bar', nargs='*', default=[1, 2, 3], help='BAR!')
```